# Cannot execute Maven project in other computer

Tags: java, maven, plugins, jar

I am getting started in Maven, so I tried to create a test project to execute it in **other PC**.

I'm using [Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) because i want just a file to execute and [Compiler Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) because in the PC where I'm executing the project only has Java 6 and in my PC I use JRE 1.8 and I believe I can use for that.

So the problem is that when I execute the project gives me an error that **cannot find the main class**.

By the way, on the computer where I created the project works perfect even with the jar in other location.

Here's my **POM file**.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>Prueba</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Prueba</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <name>Me</name>
            <organization>Company</organization>
            <organizationUrl>https://www.company.moon</organizationUrl>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.company.App</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I just changed my name and the company.

Answer (score 0):

use `<archive> <index>  <manifest>` base configration into `<configuration>`. you try this below code.

```
      <configuration>
            <archive>
                <index>true</index>
                <manifest>
                      <mainClass>com.company.App</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
```

Comment: I must put this inside shade-plugin, <executions>, <configuration> ??? If yes I already replaced the previous <configuration> for yours and doesn't work.